# Rails logs are not writing to development.log or qa.log files(whichever environment it is in), logs are only coming in console command line output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Rails logs are getting in the STD console output (i.e. command line), however, it is not writing to the development.log file. I'm able to see all my API requests logs in console output but nothing is getting written in the development.log file( development.log is getting generated but it's empty always)

Ruby version is 2.7.2
Rails version is 6.1.4.4

below is the code for application.rb, development.rb and qa.rb files.

**application.rb** file code below:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require 'action_mailbox/engine'
require 'action_text/engine'
require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"


# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module LambyRor
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true
    config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
 
    # config.active_job.queue_adapter = :shoryuken
  end
end
```

**development.rb** file code below:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'

Rails.application.configure do
  config.after_initialize do
    # Bullet.enable = true
    # Bullet.sentry = false
    # Bullet.alert = false
    # Bullet.bullet_logger = true
    # Bullet.console = false
    # Bullet.growl = false
    # Bullet.rails_logger = true
    # Bullet.honeybadger = false
    # Bullet.bugsnag = false
    # Bullet.airbrake = false
    # Bullet.rollbar = false
    # Bullet.add_footer = false
    # Bullet.skip_html_injection = false
    # Bullet.stacktrace_includes = [ 'your_gem', 'your_middleware' ]
    # Bullet.stacktrace_excludes = [ 'their_gem', 'their_middleware', ['my_file.rb', 'my_method'], ['my_file.rb', 16..20] ]
  end

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :shoryuken
  config.active_job.default_queue_name = "#{ENV['MESSAGE_QUEUE_NAME']}"

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise exceptions for disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :raise

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = false  #TODO

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  # Uncomment if you wish to allow Action Cable access from any origin.
  # config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure the availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use this for local environment
  config.hosts.clear
end
```

**qa.rb** file code below:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside the main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure the availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :shoryuken
  config.active_job.default_queue_name = "#{ENV['MESSAGE_QUEUE_NAME']}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :log

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I have tried adding the below line in development.rb, but no luck.
`config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'development.log'))`

I have also tried checking the correct environment is being used, and restarting the server, but no luck.

Also, I want to update here that another service with almost similar code but Ruby version 3.0.3 and rails 7.0.3 is getting logs written in log files. is this anywhere related to ruby/rails version that I'm currently using?

Answer (score 0):

if you want TWO loggers at the same time dont use the same variable :

```
  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  else
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new((Rails.root, 'log', 'development.log'))
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

And do not forget the write permission on the `log` file

For my development env i use :

```
ActiveSupport::Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.log")
```

Comment: thanks for the above answer. However can you please help me understand where am I using two loggers? 

also, I have tried the above answer just now, but now it's not even generating a development.log file once the server started.

Comment: i've edited my answer .
the log files should be present before , i dont know if the app generates it